# migrating two Mongo collections to new Mongo DB, and retain objectIds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-migration

This is for a Node + Mongo back end.

**Requirement:**
To migrate two collections(c1 and c2) from db1 to the same in db2.
The objectIds of documents within c1 and c2 are cross referenced.
When the c1 and c2 are migrated to db2, ideally the objectIds of their documents need to be retained, so that the cross reference works.

**Plan:**
Restore the mongoDb collections c1 and c2 from db1, in db2, without using --drop

```
mongorestore --nsFrom="db1" --nsTo="db2" --db="db2" --nsInclude="db1.c1" dump
```

However, there is a chance that some of the objectIds of docs from c1 and c2 from db1 may exist somewhere within db2(in any of the many collections). In that case the above will throw an error.
**How do I check if any of the objectId exists in db2?**

lets say `oldDocIds` is an array of objectIds of docs in c1 and c2 from db1.

I can check existence of oldDocIds in db2 collections, **one collection at a time** using the below method. But its a tedious job given too many collections in db2.

```
let count = await db2Collection1.count( { _id: { $in: oldDocIds } } );
```

**Q 1: is there a way to check this for the entire db2 in one go?**

If any objectId exists in db2, then that document will have to be inserted in db2 using a new ObjectId and its cross reference will have to be updated.

**Q 2: Is there a better way to achieving this migration for the cross referencing to work?**

Comment: It is effectively impossible for true client-side-generated `ObjectId` to be duped.  Are you talking about `_id` with a different type, like a string or int....?

Comment: There are two web applications running on different machines. Two collections from one app(hence one DB) to be migrated to DB in another app. 

Based on MongoDb ObjectId documentation, the 12-byte Mongo ObjectId consists of: A 4-byte timestamp, representing the ObjectId's creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch. A 5-byte random value generated once per process. This random value is unique to the machine and process. 

So there is a chance, ObjectId can be same on two different servers. As there are thousands of records to be migrated, want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that you will find dupes in `_id`.   Assuming you can in fact produce a (big?) array of `_id` in `oldDocIds` then just programmatically iterate over the collections and hand adjust the very few if any dupes that do pop out:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("db2"); // or whatever it is actually named...

db.getCollectionInfos().forEach(function(info) {
    if(info['type'] == 'collection') { // don't look at views...                 
        var n = info['name'];
        var coll = db.getCollection(n);

        // arg #2 projects only _id; no point in dragging back the rest of 
        // the doc...
        c = coll.find({_id: {$in: objids}},{_id:true});
        d = null;
        while(c.hasNext()) {
            d = c.next();
            print("coll", n, "dupe _id", d['_id']);
        }
        if(d == null) {  // did not find ANY dupes
            print("coll", n, "NO dupes");
        }
    }   
});
```